# mongoose.findOneAndUpdate() changes the value being saved in my Express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I found one other person asking about a value override, but its unanswered. Hopefully someone can point out the dumb thing im missing! Here's the gist...

```
var vote = req.body.vote;
var boolVote;

(vote === 'good') ? boolVote = true : boolVote = false;
                           //  these square brackets were the issue  ----------\/
Model.findOneAndUpdate({firstname:'Jane'},{$set:{'event.attempt.judge1':[boolvote]}},
                  {new: true},(err,lifter)=>{console.log(lifter.event.attempt.judge1})
```

Ive chopped it down to its basic function because in-program boolVote will console.log as the correct value (true if vote==='good', false otherwise) but no matter how i rearrange things it ALWAYS updates to the DB as true...

Originally boolVote was this

```
var boolVote = ()=>(vote === 'good') ? true : false;
```

which didnt work either. I can change the value in the mongo CLI without issue.

Has anyone else had issues saving a FALSE value to MongoDB? If so, what does it take to get this working, and if not what am i doing wrong???

Thanks in advance for any help, im pulling hair here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write ternary simply like this, i'm not familiar with js but in other program languages like `java` the syntax is same as below

```
var boolVote = vote === 'good'  ? true : false;
```

or

```
var boolVote = ( vote === 'good' )  ? true : false;
```

but when you do this

```
var boolVote = () => ( vote === 'good' )  ? true : false;
```

here `boolVote` is a `Function` with no arguments, so you need call **`boolVote()`** to get its value

**EDIT**

`event.attempt.judge1` is a field, but when enclosed with square bracket as an array in the update method, regardless of true/false the non empty array resolved to true, same updated in db

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {firstname:'Jane'},
    {$set:{'event.attempt.judge1':boolvote}}, //removed []
    {new: true},
    (err,lifter)=>{console.log(lifter.event.attempt.judge1)}
)
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, and i did update my code to match

`var boolVote = vote === 'good'  ? true : false;`

but i get the same result. console.log shows false, but the value saved is still true

Comment: can you print `req.params.vote` to console on both the cases true and false

Comment: I can indeed. the log is correct in both cases. Ive also tried being type non-specific `(vote == 'good') true : false` which is the same result, and `(vote = 'good') ? true : false` which is always true

Comment: can you also paste the value of `var vote = req.params.vote`

Comment: Im not certain of what you're asking. `var vote` does always correctly equal `'good'` or `'bad'` depending on the request, and `var boolVote` does always correspond correctly as either `true` or `false`

for the record these are POST requests, so i suppose i could simply move the variable to a hidden input in the HTML instead of using it as a URL parameter

Comment: just wanted to ensure that `req.params.vote` is always good or bad, so printing this might give an idea ?

Comment: It does print correctly everytime. Though i havent found any Docs to support this, i was thinking that possibly Express' router didn't like req.params with POST requests (even though it prints correctly) so i moved it to the HTML-side in the form. 
It still prints correctly, but also still saves to the DB as `true` regardless

so now `vote = req.body.vote` and everything else on the backend is the same

Comment: can you set `mongoose.set('debug', true);` in your js, and see what's being sent to db?

Comment: That shows my limited knowledge with this. I didnt realize i could log everything that simply... Here is the log, which shows the value as `true` even though `boolVote` does still return as `false`.

`Mongoose: lifters.findAndModify({ member: 'SD6F5S4D56SD5' }, [], { '$set': { 'squat.one.judge1': true } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })`

Comment: `squat.one.judge1` is array or filed in db?

Comment: squat.one.judge1 is a single value in a nested object.

here is an excerpt of the model (its a big model)

  squat:{
    flight:String,
    liftno:{
      type:String,
      default:null
    },
    one:{
      weight:Number,
      judge1:Boolean,
      judge2:Boolean,
      judge3:Boolean,
      record:String
    },

Comment: got it the issue is with the square bracket you have in the update code, see the edit

Comment: AH! sure enough. the square brackets are required for variables as the key. I didnt realize that they werent required for the value itself, that fixed it right up! 
Thank you, i really appreciate the help